# Trends on time spent studying over the the past few decades, for students outside the US

Tags: coursework, reference-request, working-time, academic-history

Is there any research/study/survey/dataset that looked at the trends on the time students spent on studying, over the the past few decades in different countries in the world (aside from the [USA](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/61383/452))?

I am mostly interested in the field of computer science, if field-specific, and college level, if level-specific.

Comment: In case anyone else tries the same thing I did: the OP is the same as on [the earlier question about why study time in the US has declined](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61383/why-has-the-time-spent-studying-declined-so-sharply-in-the-united-states-over-th), and so the linked sources in there probably aren't satisfactory.

Comment: What are you trying to ask about the US that is not already answered by the data set in the other question?

Comment: @chipbuster yes my question contains a link to this question.

Comment: @jakebeal ok I'll exclude USA from the question. I am indeed looking for something similar for other countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Germany the data is there in the form of the "Studierenden survey", which exists since 1982. However, I don't know if it is analysed. The datasets are available, so I added a list of links to the datasets for the different years in case you want to do the analysis yourself.

2012/13: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.5126

2009/10: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.11059

2006/07: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.4263

2003/04: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.4344

2000/01: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.4208

1997/98: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.3511

1994/95: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.3131

1992/93: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.3130

1989/90: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.2417

1986/87: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.2416

1984/85: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.1885

1982/83: http://dx.doi.org/10.4232/1.1884